# Convert between template types?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template

```cpp
template <typename T=std::nullptr_t>
class Foo{

Foo(T&){};

};
```

Unfortunately, this fails when `T` is `void`. `std::nullptr_t` would serve the exact same purpose here, and I would much prefer that to be `T`.

Is there a way to designate that all `Foo<void>` should be `Foo<std::nullptr_t>` instead?

Comment: What do you want to use the template for?

Comment: @PasserBy To contain the return type of a function.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you specialize `Foo<void>` instead. Substituting with another type is mightily confusing.

Comment: A function might return `std::nullptr_t` (even if usage would be limited).

Answer (score 3):

If you want `Foo<void>` to actually be identical to `Foo<std::nullptr_t>`, you need to make `Foo` an alias template:

```
template <typename T>
class FooImpl {
    FooImpl(T&);
};

template <typename T=std::nullptr_t>
using Foo = FooImpl<std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, std::nullptr_t, T>>;
```

If you don't want to use an alias, you can still make `Foo<void>` have the same constructor signature as `Foo<std::nullptr_t>`. Nonetheless, they will be two separate types:

```
template <typename T=std::nullptr_t>
class Foo{
    using reference = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, std::nullptr_t, T>&;
    Foo(reference);
};
```